# target platform supports only STATIC libraries not shared library issue

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am trying to compile c++ project on Redhat Linux 4.1.2 machine using Cmake utility.
In CMakeLists.txt i have specfied GenericUSMModules as follows.

```
ADD_LIBRARY(
        GenericUSMModules SHARED 
          ../../Generic/GenericUSMModules/GMUSMActState.cpp
          ../../Generic/GenericUSMModules/GMUSMActState.h
          ../../Generic/GenericUSMModules/GMUSMAdditionalOfferChecksAndEdits.cpp
          ../../Generic/GenericUSMModules/GMUSMAdditionalOfferChecksAndEdits.h
          ../../Generic/GenericUSMModules/GMUSMAlignmentOfProductsConfigurationAndStrategicOrderManagerChecksAndEdits.cpp
          ../../Generic/GenericUSMModules/GMUSMAlignmentOfProductsConfigurationAndStrategicOrderManagerChecksAndEdits.h
          ../../Generic/GenericUSMModules/GMUSMAllSitePart2SiteChecksAndEdits.cpp

    )
```

when i run make command to compile c++ project , i got following error.
"ADD_LIBRARY for library GenericUSMModules is used with the SHARED option, 
but the target platform supports only STATIC libraries. Building it STATIC instead.
 This may lead to problems."
I am not able to understand meaning of platform doesn't support share library.
because after compilation, it generate static library(GenericUSMModules.a) not share library(GenericUSMModules.so)
please help me in this regard.

Comment: Did you mean RHEL 4.1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of search i found that issue is due to incompatible cmake on RehHat Linux Machine.
I installed latest cmake 2.8.8 on RedHat. It solved problem and now it generates share library(.so files).